# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i am getting this error, i just want to make a function that return all indexes of an array, but i dont know if i doing something wrong, it just shows an error than push can not be used, becouse undefined value.

here the code:

```
    function getIindex(array){
      let values
      for (let [ index, value ] of array.entries()) {
        values.push(index)
        console.log(values)
      }  
      return values
    }  

    let indexSubIndustry = getIindex(subRows)
```

Comment: What is the point to get all the indexes of array. I mean its pretty obvious they all be from `0` to `array.length - 1`

Comment: @MaheerAli my sentiments exactly, odd requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the `values` variable with a value, empty array in your case.

```
function getIindex(array){
  let values = []; // here
  for (let [ index, value ] of array.entries()) {
    values.push(index)
    console.log(values)
  }  
  return values
}  

let indexSubIndustry = getIindex(subRows)
```

You might need to specify type hint for that array, depending on your TS configuration (e.g. with strict mode enabled).

```
let values: number[] = [];
```

Btw your code can be simplified a lot, if you want to return keys of the `array` parameter, just use `keys()` method:

```
function getIindex(array){
  return [...array.keys()]; // convert iterator to array
}
```

Comment: oh, thank you. it worked, i believed that with ES6 it was not neccesary to inicializate an array.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign your values as an empty array instead of keeping it undefined.

```js
let values = [];

// Rest of the code
```